# PHP script that returns an error message based on what $_POST parameters are missing

Tags: php

I have a script that checks if the specified set of `$_POST` variables are supplied and not empty and returns an error string that is human readable.

Here's my code:

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // Local variables initialization
    $missing = [];

    $checkVariables = [
        'name', 'address', 'contact'
    ];

    // Check for nulls or non existent payload
    foreach ($checkVariables as $item) {
        if (empty($_POST[$item]) || !array_key_exists($item, $_POST)) {
            $missing[] = $item;
        }
    }

    $missingCount = count($missing);
    if ($missingCount > 0) {
        $missingString = '';

        if ($missingCount === 1) {
            $missingString = $missing[0];
        } else if ($missingCount === 2) {
            $missingString = implode(' and ', $missing);
        } else {
            $lastItem = array_pop($missing);
            $partialMissingString = implode(', ', $missing);

            $missingString = $partialMissingString . ", and {$lastItem}";
        }

        $verb = $missingCount > 1 ? 'are' : 'is';
        $field = $missingCount > 1 ? 'fields' : 'field';
        $errorString = "Incomplete information received. " .
            "The {$missingString} {$field} {$verb} missing. " .
            "Please check your inputs and try again.";

        // Exits the script
        OutputResponse::sendResponse(400, $errorString);
    }
    // if there's no missing continue running the script
    // more code here but it's not the focus of this code review
}
```

My `OutputResponse` code:

```php
class OutputResponse
{
    public static function sendResponse(string $statusCode, $messageBody): void
    {
        if ($statusCode == 500) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        } else if ($statusCode == 405) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
        } else if ($statusCode == 404) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        } else if ($statusCode == 403) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        } else if ($statusCode == 401) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
        } else if ($statusCode == 400) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode([
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'data' => $messageBody
        ]);

        exit;
    }
}
```

---

The script expects `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['address']`, and `$_POST['contact']` to be not null or empty. The array keys to be checked are in the `$checkVariables` array.

For simplification, I'm dropping the `$_POST` in the next examples.

If `name` is the only one missing:

```json
{
    "code": "400",
    "data": "Incomplete information received. The name field is missing. Please check your inputs and try again."
}
```

If `name` and `contact` are missing:

```json
{
    "code": "400",
    "data": "Incomplete information received. The name and contact fields are missing. Please check your inputs and try again."
}
```

If all three are missing:

```json
{
    "code": "400",
    "data": "Incomplete information received. The name, address, and contact fields are missing. Please check your inputs and try again."
}
```

---

Personally, the part on the `if ($missingCount > 0)` block is the messiest or unoptimized.

Any improvements or critiques are welcome!

Comment: I would wrap the field name in quotes/double quotes in your error message to indicate that it's being referred to as a word. e.g. `The field "foo" is missing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `if (empty($_POST[$item]) || !array_key_exists($item, $_POST)) {` is literally checking if `$_POST[$item]` is not declared or is falsey THEN checking if `$_POST[$item]` is not declared.

   > ```
   > // Check for nulls or non existent payload
   > ```

   The comment associated with the step indicates that you want to check if `$_POST` elements are not declared or are `null`.  In this case, you should only use:
    `if (!isset($_POST[$item])) {`.

   If you want to check that elements are not declared or empty/falsey, then use:
   `if (empty($_POST[$item])) {`.
2. `if ($missingCount > 0) {` can be safely reduced to `if ($missingCount) {` which checks if the count is "truthy" (in other words, not zero).
3. `else if` is one word in php, please always type `elseif` to comply with PSR guidelines.
4. Don't bother declaring `$missingString = '';` if you are unconditionally going to overwrite it anyhow.
5. You can combine the `if` and first `else if` because if the array only has one element, then no glue will be used while producing the output string.

   ```
   if ($missingCount < 3) {
        $missingString = implode(' and ', $missing);
   }
   ```
6. The "smart-implode" as I've seen it referred to at least once on StackOverflow is fine enough.  There are [a few other ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193927/2943403) -- I'll show another one below.
7. The whole chunk of code that crafts the OutputResponse might look like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/quMIB)).  The advantages are: fewest declared variables (specifically no single-use variables), not repeated function calls, and the elegance of `sprintf()` when injecting variables into a string.

   ```
   $missingCount = count($missing);
   if ($missingCount) {
       if ($missingCount < 3) {
            $glue = ' and ';
       } else {
            $glue = ', ';
            $missing[] = 'and ' . array_pop($missing);
       }
       OutputResponse::sendResponse(
           400,
           sprintf(
               'Incomplete information received. The %s %s missing. Please check your inputs and try again.',
               implode($glue, $missing),
               $missingCount === 1 ? 'field is' : 'fields are'
           )
       );
   }
   ```
8. [EDITED] After reading the other reviews and learning that my recommended lookup array was incomplete, flawed, and frankly suboptimal, I now find myself agreeing with YourCommonSense's advice to use `http_response_code()` for setting the HTTP response code.  See [this Stack Overflow page for additional considerations and fringe cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258634/2943403) around the native function which was available since PHP5.4. Also,  Now I suppose my new code for the `sendResponse()` method would look like this:

   ```
    http_response_code($statusCode);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(
        json_encode([
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'data' => $messageBody
        ])
    );
   ```

Comment: There's a minor bug with your lookup where you could output (for example) a `301 OK` response header

Comment: I intentionally did not change the behavior of the OP's code.  I did not know if they specifically wanted this behavior.

Comment: Sorry, but you have (maybe unintentionally), changed the behaviour of the OPs code. In three ways: **First** the `$statusCode` returned is a formatted header and not the integer that the OP has, **secondly** the code above exits without sending any header so actually a `200 OK` header will be sent not the `400 Bad Request` which the OP intends, and **third** the formatted header (which isn't set and is instead returned to the wrong place) will always be `XXX OK` unless it's explicitly in the `$codes` array; the OP originally output a `200 OK` if `$statusCode` didn't match

Comment: Also, I'm aware that that probably sounds far more confrontational than I intended! Apologies for that, it's tricky to get the point across with limited characters without being direct

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I'll edit when I get out of my garden.  The function declaration and the header were omitted because I was only addressing the lookup (not providing a full function body.

Answer (score 4):

### OutputResponse

**Quotation marks**

This is hugely pedantic: your `405` header response uses single quotes where as all of the others use double quotes. It makes no difference (in fact single quotes are slightly faster for plain text in `PHP`), however, it's good practice to stick to one method especially when setting near identical strings.

**Type hints & Parameters**

You have a `string` type hint on your `integer` parameter and **no** type hint at all for your `$messageBody` parameter?

Currently you pass an integer...

```
OutputResponse::sendResponse(400, $errorString);
```

... to a parameter of type string...

```
function sendResponse(string $statusCode, $messageBody)
```

... and then compare it as an integer...

```
if ($statusCode == 500)
else if ($statusCode == 405)
...
```

... which is confusing on many levels and presumably not intended behaviour?

So that needs to be fixed, while there I would also swap your parameter order around too; then you can set a default value of, for example, `200` for your `$statusCode`.

```
public static function sendResponse(string $statusCode, $messageBody): void

// Becomes....

public static function sendResponse(string $messageBody, int $statusCode = 200) : void
```

**HTTP Status: logic**

Currently you're using a series of `if/else` statements to work out what HTTP response code to send. This can be tricky to read and isn't always clear what the code block attempts to do; `switch` is pretty much designed for this exact use case although personally I would use an array for this type of task.

Also, I wouldn't put the `header(...)` function call in every `if` statement. Much better to put one call at the end and return the string from the logic.

One more note is that you have your code set up to default to `200 OK` if the response code doesn't exist in the block. This is wrong IMO: if your own code doesn't know what response to give then I doubt everything is `OK`? I'd opt for something like a generic `500`, because the server has obviously run into a problem!

*Note: `500` doesn't automatically mean fatal*

Using `switch`:

```
$header = "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error";
switch $statusCode{
    case 500:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error";
        break;
    case 405:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed";
        break;
    case 404:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found";
        break;
    case 403:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden";
        break;
    case 401:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized";
        break;
    case 400:
        $header = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request";
        break;
} 

header($header);
```

Using an `array`:

```
$httpStatus = [
    500 => "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error",
    405 => "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed",
    404 => "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found",
    403 => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden",
    401 => "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized",
    400 => "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request",
    200 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
];

header($httpStatus[$StatusCode] ?? $httpStatus[500]);
```

**HTTP status: code**

I'm not 100% onboard with sending a `400 Bad Request` response in this scenario.

Perhaps you can call this personal preference or what not but as far as I can tell this is some form of `ajax` style set up? In which case the *client side* script is sending a request to the server which then acts upon it. Your *server side* script then gets hold of the header content and makes it's own checks... Which means that the HTTP request did succeed, the script (resource) was executed, and content was even generated.

The fact is, it isn't a HTTP issue, the user just hasn't submitted the correct details. You obviously implement your own error reporting to come back with application errors - so just set a code or a message in there (which is what you have done anyway) and leave the `HTTP` response code alone.

### Main Code

**`REQUEST_METHOD`**

There's really no need for your opening (all encompassing) `if` statement. The whole purpose of the code block is to check that the `$_POST` variables are present and correct and if they aren't stop the execution of further code with `exit;`. By using the `===` comparison operator all you're doing is opening yourself up to issues in the event of a badly structured request where the method isn't formed as all caps (of course, this *shouldn't* be a problem in 2021 but you can't be sure).

Again, if the `REQUEST_METHOD` isn't `POST` then the rest of the code fails and exits anyway. So why waste the time checking?

**`if`: logic**

The second condition in your first `if` statement is redundant: if the index doesn't exist then the first condition is effectively `empty(null)` which, of course, is `true`. So checking afterwards to see if the array key exists isn't doing anything extra.

```
if (empty($_POST[$item]) || !array_key_exists($item, $_POST))

// Becomes...

if (empty($_POST[$item]))
```

Later on you use `$missingCount > 0` which is okay, but... Not needed: `count` will return either `0` or some positive value greater than `0`. Logically `0 == false` so you can just skip the comparison; if the value is `0` then it's false, otherwise, its `true`.

```
if ($missingCount > 0)

// Becomes...

if ($missingCount)
```

**String assembly**

Custom error messages are tricky: they have to be informative but succinct, forceful but polite, etc. You don't want to annoy your user with a lengthy error message or, worse still, intimidate them with overly aggressive language.

So, my suggestion, would be to simply change the error message:

```
$errorString   = "Incomplete information received. Please check the following fields:";
```

Now all you need to do is append your variables to the end of the string. Which means we can reduce your code to a simple loop:

```
foreach ($checkVariables as $item) {
    $errorFields .= empty($_POST[$item]) ? "{$item}, " : "";
}
```

This leaves you with a trailing comma and no `and` so we do need to do a little formatting; but now you have a piece of code that scales automatically if you need to add more variables for example maybe you start collecting `$_POST["phoneNumber"]`.

```
$errorString .= rtrim(preg_replace("/, (\w+), $/", " and $1", $errorFields), ", ");
```

*This, I believe, is technically also the fastest method despite implementing regular expressions*

If you're against changing your error message this is compatible with your current logic to work out plural etc. just use `$errorFields` and then concatenate as you see fit.

### Updated Code

**Main Body**

```
$checkVariables = ['name', 'address', 'contact'];
$errorString    = "Incomplete information received. Please check the following fields: ";
$errorFields    = "";

foreach ($checkVariables as $item) {
    $errorFields .= empty($_POST[$item]) ? "{$item}, " : "";
}

$errorString .= rtrim(preg_replace("/, (\w+), $/", " and $1", $errorFields), ", ");

if ($errorFields) {
    OutputResponse::sendResponse(400, $errorString);
}
```

**OutputResponse**

```
class OutputResponse
{
    public static function sendResponse(string $messageBody, int $statusCode = 200) : void
    {
        $httpStatus = [
            500 => "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error",
            405 => "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed",
            404 => "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found",
            403 => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden",
            401 => "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized",
            400 => "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request",
            200 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
        ];

        header($httpStatus[$StatusCode] ?? $httpStatus[500]);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo json_encode([
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'data' => $messageBody
        ]);

        exit;
    }
}
```

*or, my preference...*

```
class OutputResponse
{
    public static function sendResponse(string $messageBody, int $statusCode = 200) : void
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo json_encode([
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'data' => $messageBody
        ]);

        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see some redundant review points with this review that already exist in other answers.  Please spare the OP re-reading the same insights by only mentioning new insights.  If you agree with / support insights from other reviewers, you can express your agreement in your answer without repeating it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I did check the `guidelines` before posting because I wasn't sure whether to remove them or not... But the only real _duplicate_ is probably `> 0` (and potentially `empty()`) everything else seems - to me at least - have a different slant? But who knows, I'm knew here and wasn't sure on etiquette (also I figured an answer has been accepted already so it didn't matter too much)

Comment: At the end of the day, my stance on your posting style is that it errs on the side of generosity and therefore raises the expected standard of other reviews.  For that reason, I hope that you settle in and continue reviewing.  And yes, perhaps the truthy check is the only redundancy.

Comment: @mickmackusa a review is like a sculpture - written the way one sees it. I don't think there should be any restrictions in this regard. I would rather love to see http_response_code() used in your answers. Although I do understand that a lookup array is used as a generic example for fixing this kind of code but why stop here if you have even better optimization for this specific case?

Comment: I will edit my answer.  I am spending all day in my garden.  My opinion is that there is no benefit to the OP or future researchers/reviewers to see the exact same insight twice.  @You

Comment: @mickmackusa in my experience (mostly personal), people seldom catch the new information at the first take. It takes several attempts, probably at different angles to get it right. I see no harm in the duplicated suggestion. It just means more emphasis

Comment: Regarding this answer, I am in huge doubts about the personal preference part. In my world, HTTP status codes are precious, being a lingua franca for the inter-system interaction.  I may be don't understand what is said in the text response but I surely understands the HTTP status code. It makes the logic simpler and allows me to use a premade library with standard responses to standard codes, instead of writing some logic by hand.

Comment: It is just as easy to acknowledge an earlier reviews insights if you want to give more emphasis.  Simply say, "I agree with [user]'s review in using a truthy check on the error count." Or  "I agree with [user]'s review in using a falsey check instead of `empty()`."This shows that the new reviewer bothered to read the earlier reviews before posting a new one and the OP gets the emphasis without seeing it mansplained a second time.

Comment: @mickmackusa but he is not required to "read the other reviews" :) Come on, that's not the topic to argue over. It smells like a gatekeeping. Let's just have as much good reviews as possible, and disregard such petty concerns. Or well let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: I do not appreciate the accusation of being a "gatekeeper" after I already gave justifications for why I feel reading the other answers and not repeating insights is better for the community and the OP.  I'll have a look around Meta (when I get out of the garden) to see if there is any discussion on this etiquette.

Comment: So this seems to have taken a turn I did not expect! I obviously did _"read the other reviews"_ before posting, I thought, that was clear as I have also commented on both answers? This review only **really* duplicates the two points I mentioned in an earlier comment(?) and even then the explanation is different. I would hope that explanation isn't considered _mansplaining_ it just clarifies what is actually going on and why the additional code is redundant; is it not better to explain reasoning so that the OP doesn't blindly go off and use similar practices without understanding?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, I suppose that's one way to look at it. My _question_ is what benefit does it provide? A HTTP response code tells the browser that something's wrong with the request, not an _ordinary_ user? Sending a `200 OK` means the browser (and the client scripts etc.) know that the request succeeded and the internal `error code/message` tells the script what happened with the server script logic... If using a HTTP code to return script logic then where's the line? Would you, for example, return a `400` for an incorrect username/password? Or debugging a typo in the ajax URL?

Comment: Surely it's about client scripts. A ready made library *already* understands 500 and 404, u don't have to write any code by hand to handle it. Whether I would or would not handle 400 is my choice. the problem is, when it's always 200, then there is **no choice**. After all, sending proper http codes is **defined by the standard**. But what I don't understand the most, why this question at all. Adding proper http code costs you absolutely nothing. I really don't see any reason to argue against them.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I suppose my view is that in this scenario a HTTP response code isn't the proper response? A `4XX` error means something  like: _"...the server doesn't/can't understand/handle the request..."_ but the server and the script - in this case - were able to handle the request, it's the content which is in question. So to me a `200 OK` with feed back is appropriate? I'm not saying I would never use them, for example, if I try to access a `users page` without logging in I might expect to see a `403` (I would probably opt for a re-direct). Maybe I'm wrong or maybe we're both right ‍

Comment: as long as you are **using** a standard HTTP status code in the response body, there is not a single reason not to use it in the HTTP response header. If you don't see any use for the codes, why send them at all

Comment: @mickmackusa also, I have commented on a previous review of yours with suggestions rather than providing a complete solution; because to do so would have given largely the same content (code) in an optimised order? There is guidance on [how to answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which suggests that reviews can cover the same points so long as there is at least one unique point - so I guess that's down to interpretation - and I would say that all but a very small section is unique points? Also, your answer was accepted when I posted... So it doesn't detract?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wouldn't use the same HTTP code in this scenario I would implement an internal error system that provides standard error messages for application specific errors - you have to do this anyway to provide output/feedback (e.g. _wrong password_). Using a HTTP code potentially masks where the code has arisen. Again, I would call it personal preference I'm not saying that sending a HTTP response code is strictly wrong?

Answer (score 3):

An interesting approach.

Being a dev, I never bothered myself with proper English syntax, using just implode and calling it a day. but yours looks definitely better. Regarding optimization, you may notice that a condition `$missingCount === 2` is actually covered by else case, so it can be removed. Or so I think because I believe that the last comma is superfluous in  `name, address, and contact`.

Also, a trick I myself learned not long ago, is `http_status_code()` function which *alone* replaces the whole `if ($statusCode == 500) { ...` ladder, sending the proper header when called. So you can make it *just*

```
http_response_code($statusCode);
```

and call it a day.

It will also eliminate that awkward type juggling when you are sending a string status to the function and then have to compare it using == operator.

Comment: I would have guessed that the type juggling `int >> string >> int` isn't intentional and the type hinting should be updated?